# How to change/reset CRM 2013 password on-premises?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to change or reset Customer Relationship Management 2013 Password on-premises.

Comment: Belongs on ServerFault: CRM authenticates against Active Directory so user's Windows password must be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You Want to Change **Crm OnPremises** Password Change Your Windows Password.For Crm OnPremises we can enable or disable WindowsAuthentication Using Browsers settings.Internet Explore in security --> custom level --> logon --> and set to prompt for user name and password.